# SQL / MYSQL : returning first marching row vs min calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking in a table "db_operators_wk_days" <strike>the first matching result for a given date for each operator.</strike>

**EDIT** : To be more explicit I'm looking for the first time range where a given operator will be available

"db_operators_wk_days":

```
         id       |  operator_id    |    start_time         |     end_time     
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
         1        |       1         |  2017-11-05 08:00:00  | 2017-11-05 17:00:00  
         2        |       1         |  2017-11-06 07:00:00  | 2017-11-06 11:00:00 
         3        |       1         |  2017-11-09 08:00:00  | 2017-11-09 17:00:00 
      .....       |     ......
      3001        |       2         |  2017-11-07 07:00:00  | 2017-11-07 17:00:00  
      3002        |       2         |  2017-11-08 08:00:00  | 2017-11-08 17:00:00 
      3003        |       2         |  2017-11-09 08:00:00  | 2017-11-09 17:00:00 
      .....       |     ......
      8001        |       3         |  2017-11-05 12:00:00  | 2017-11-05 23:00:00  
      8002        |       3         |  2017-11-12 08:00:00  | 2017-11-12 17:00:00 
      8003        |       3         |  2017-11-13 08:00:00  | 2017-11-13 17:00:00 
      .....       |     ......
```

So far I came with a query which does the job:

```
SET @date='2017-11-05 22:30:00';
SELECT operator_id,  start_time, end_time
FROM db_operators_wk_days
WHERE id IN (
           SELECT min(id) 
             FROM db_operators_wk_days 
            WHERE end_time>@date
            GROUP BY operator_id
         );
```

Results :

```
operator_id     |   start_time           |    end_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    1           |  2017-11-06 07:00:00   |   2017-11-06 11:00:00
    2           |  2017-11-07 07:00:00   |   2017-11-07 17:00:00
    3           |  2017-11-05 12:00:00   |   2017-11-05 23:00:00
```

It's already good but I'm looking to improve it because I'll do plenty of requests (thousands and thousands) with this.

The following subquery   :

```
SELECT min(id) 
FROM db_operators_wk_days 
WHERE end_time>@date
GROUP BY operator_id
ORDER BY NULL;
```

is the one taking the most time. It seems logical since the queried table can be quiet heavy and since the min operation looks at all the records.

I'm looking to improve this. Since the ids are ordered in the "db_operators_wk_days" table, is there a way to grab the first matching result instead of doing the min calculation?

PS : to my surprise while I was working on this I found that the following subquery was giving the good results twice faster (4ms vs 8ms) but I don't understand why it works!

```
SELECT  id
FROM db_operators_wk_days 
WHERE end_time>@date
GROUP BY operator_id;
```

Comment: What does "first" mean? (Why "order by null"??) Tables have no order; result sets have order. Also that final query uses a non-standard extension that involves returning an arbitrary element from a set, so it is *not* correct and not guaranteed to give you the right answer. These are all faqs & so is your question--if you phrased your question clearly. Google. PS Why thousands instead of one, with all the dates you need?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought for the last query, just a question of luck.
To be more explicit I'm looking for the first time range where my operator will be available for a given date.

So if I have as an input date '2017-11-05 22:30:00' it will tell me that the first (or next) time range  where my the operator 1 will be available is :

   2017-11-06 07:00:00   -->  2017-11-06 11:00:00

Comment: Read about indexes/indexing & SARGability. If you're going to query for big dates, you probably an index where dates are ordered, though that will trade off with other things like updates.

Comment: I forgot to answer to one point in your first answer. This query runs thousands of time because it's used in a genetic algorithm where I explore thousands of different solutions to build a production schedule.

Comment: Yes but you should put them in a table & get all the corresponding values at once. (I realize though that which you ask for could depend on branchings in the algorithm.) And you should push as much of the algorithm into a query as you can. PS Where you are clarifying your answer, edit your answer rather than making a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the query as a correlated subquery:

```
SET @date = '2017-11-05 22:30:00';

SELECT owd.operator_id, owd.start_time, owd.end_time
FROM db_operators_wk_days owd
WHERE owd.end_time > @date AND
      owd.id = (SELECT MIN(owd2.id) 
                FROM db_operators_wk_days owd2
                WHERE owd2.operator_id = owd.operator_id AND
                      owd2.end_time > @date
               );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `db_operators_wk_days(operator_id, end_time, id)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately the request doesn't return any rows. To work on existing data I made the following fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afLYf3wGEaGGi4PtRy8whs/3

Comment: There was an error in the `WHERE` condition in the subquery.  It is now fixed.

Comment: Great. The query is working. One last question : I added indexes on the suggested columns by doing 

    ALTER TABLE db_operators_wk_days ADD INDEX db_operators_wk_days(operator_id, end_time, id);

It improved speed but I'm not sure I did it right. An EXPLAIN query is attached on this page : 
[DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afLYf3wGEaGGi4PtRy8whs/4)

Comment: @SebastienD . . . New questions (such as about performance) should be asked as new questions and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Great. This query is working. 
I added indexes on the suggested columns by doing

```
ALTER TABLE db_operators_wk_days ADD INDEX db_operators_wk_days(operator_id, end_time, id);
```

It improved speed but I'm not sure I did it right. The EXPLAIN query shows the following:

[image]

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/afLYf3wGEaGGi4PtRy8whs/4)